# Code text appears instead of executing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need some helping loading my JavaScript game on Chrome.

I wanted to code the traditional Snake game in JavaScript using a framework called [p5.js](https://p5js.org/), and I started with the canvas. The problem happens when I open the JavaScript file in Chrome (which I linked in my index.html file with a script tag).

Instead of the grey canvas appearing, per my JavaScript code, the code itself shows up on the Chrome page. Here's my code, have a look:

HTML
    
     Snake | JS

```
<body>
<script src="F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\addons\p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\addons\p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="F:\Code\JS\Snake\sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the JS:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
}

function draw() {
    background(51);
}
```

Specs:

Chrome, Windows 10 Anniversary Edition.

P.S. Javascript is enabled, I have checked.

Comment: Did you include opening of `<html>` tag at the begining of document?

Comment: Sounds like `index.html` is actually `index.html.txt` or something. Leastways the problem is that the browser is treating the file as text and not as HTML. This has nothing to do with the JavaScript.

Comment: @Arkej — The start tag for the HTML element is optional in HTML.

Comment: you need to write your js inside the script tag

Comment: You say you 'opened the JS file in Chrome', you should instead open `index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these things

1) Test your js code on www.codepen.io/pen/, some javascript doesn't run properly when local. (F:\Code)

2) Try to put your script at the end of the body tag. Attention that the scripts are loaded in the order they appear. Consider the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the path F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\ to your files are correct and you are not working in a zipped folder.

You should have a file like index.html, wich will be the root of your website.

Here's a minimal example, including your scripts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titre de la page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

  <script src = "F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src = "F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\addons\p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src = "F:\Code\JS\p5\p5-zip\addons\p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src = "F:\Code\JS\Snake\sketch.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. Your javascript files should be placed in the bottom of the page,
   just before the closing body tag
2. You must reference your js file in a good order for preventing some dependency issues
3. If you are able to browse your index.html file, right click on the page -> "show source code" and try to click on your js files reference, if the path is not correct you will have a 404 not found error.